# How to scheduling push notifications using azure sdk for node

Tags: node.js, azure, apple-push-notifications, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

I know it is possible in .net, i can see the reference over here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-send-push-notifications-scheduled. But I want to know how to do that in node. Can any one guide me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a scheduled notification in Node using the REST API. Use the specification for sending a normal notification and replace `/messages` with `/schedulednotifications`. You will also need to add a header specifying the datetime named `ServiceBusNotification-ScheduleTime`.

For an example using the template schema:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var axios = require("axios");


var getSelfSignedToken = function(targetUri, sharedKey, keyName,
    expiresInMins) {
    targetUri = encodeURIComponent(targetUri.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase();

    // Set expiration in seconds
    var expireOnDate = new Date();
    expireOnDate.setMinutes(expireOnDate.getMinutes() + expiresInMins);
    var expires = Date.UTC(expireOnDate.getUTCFullYear(), expireOnDate
    .getUTCMonth(), expireOnDate.getUTCDate(), expireOnDate
    .getUTCHours(), expireOnDate.getUTCMinutes(), expireOnDate
    .getUTCSeconds()) / 1000;
    var tosign = targetUri + '\n' + expires;

    // using CryptoJS
    var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(tosign, sharedKey);
    var base64signature = signature.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    var base64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(base64signature);

    // construct autorization string
    var token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + targetUri + "&sig="
    + base64UriEncoded + "&se=" + expires + "&skn=" + keyName;
    // console.log("signature:" + token);
    return token;
    };


var keyName = "<mykeyName>";
var sharedKey = "<myKey>";
var uri = "https://<mybus>.servicebus.windows.net/<myhub>";
var expiration = 10;

var token = getSelfSignedToken(uri, sharedKey, keyName, expiration);

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: uri,
    timeout: 100000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'X-WNS-Type': 'wns/raw',
        'ServiceBusNotification-Format' : 'template',
        'ServiceBusNotification-ScheduleTime': '2019-07-19T17:13',
        'authorization': token}
  });

var payload = { 
            "alert" : " This is my test notification!"
    };


instance.post('/schedulednotifications?api-version=2016-07', payload)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Here's the API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/. There is an SDK for Node but it does not include the scheduled notification option. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial

Comment: Even in the rest API section I didn't find any API like scheduling cancel scheduling. If you know that link kindly share that one

Comment: According to my research the endpoint isn't currently documented. I've reached out to our docs team to get it added. In the meantime, you should be able to use the same specification for the /messages endpoint with the extra header.

Comment: If I set ServiceBusNotification-Apns-Expiry value in this request it was throwing invalid value I am giving the utc

Comment: It's worth noting that the `/schedulednotifications` endpoint is only available on the Standard pricing tier, not the cheaper ones.

Comment: Do we know what timezone is ServiceBusNotification-ScheduleTime in since the format doesn't appear to be RFC3339?